# How to know whether a file located in compressed drive?

Tags: file, mfc

I am doing an MFC application. I want to get the status of a file, whether it is in **compressed drive** or not?? I do have the filepath

I dont know the API for that please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`GetFileAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and check for `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED` ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/gg258117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Another alternative is to use [`SHGetFileInfo`](https://www.google.co.uk/#newwindow=1&q=shgetfileinfo) to retrieve the file attributes, and then look for `SFGAO_COMPRESSED` ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb762589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).